# underscore size method not counting the duplicate key value pairs

Tags: underscore.js

I have a object, which has duplicate instance within it. while i check the length of the object using size method using underscore it show the wrong value. it's not counting the duplicate instance.

how to count including duplicate or how to remove the duplicate key val pairs?

here is the sample:

```
oldData = {id: null, currency: "japan",  currency: "indian"};

console.log(_.size(oldData)) //it gives me 2 but I have 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `oldData` will have only two keys. Duplicated keys will be replaced with the last one.
Try to run the code in any JavaScript console and check the value of `oldData` directly.

```
> var oldData = {id: null, currency: "japan",  currency: "indian"};
  undefined

> oldData
  Object {id: null, currency: "indian"}
```

As you can see, `oldData` has only one `currency` key. That's why `_.size(oldData)` returns 2 instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

The size is not in error.

An object is like a set of its keys. You can **not** have two identical members in a a set.

It would be like declaring 2 variables with the same name.

- On the first use you'd set a value to your variable
- then you would just overwrite it's value
- **!!!** under no circumstances would you create a second variable with the same name differentiated only by their values.

An object behaves pretty much like a variable set or like a name-space in a way.